# Create Save button with jQuery on Drupal

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I want to create save button to save special nodes manually.

My form:

```
<form action="" name="115" method="POST">
   <button type="submit" id="edit-actionupdatedatebijan" name="115"  
           value="SAVE" class="form-submit">SAVE NODE</button>
</form
```

PHP:

```
$node = node_load(115);
node_save($node);
```

I want to process this code with jQuery, but I don't want to call external a PHP file for security reasons.

Comment: did you ever here about ajax ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by an "external php file"?

Comment: i need just run php codes with ajax or jquery for prevent refresh pages...

Comment: You can't save data on the server without running code in the server so you'll have to use PHP.

Comment: What's your suggestion ?